# Merge IP Ranges with PHP

Tags: php, sorting, ip

I am stuck at a point and cant think beyond it :

I have a list of Ip ranges, I need to merge them making them as a range. For example

> 192.168.1.1
>
> 192.168.1.2
>
> 192.168.1.3
>
> 192.168.1.5
>
> 192.168.1.6

I need to club them into IP ranges. For this case it will be `192.168.1.1`-`192.168.1.3` and `192.168.1.5`-`192.168.1.6`

I was thinking of converting these into integer by using `ip2long` function and sorting it. But can't think beyond that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks In advance :)

Comment: `ip2long` function is good enough, isn't it ?

Comment: I am thinking to use the same . But not sure about using natsort in php

Comment: @Aditi what is your list of ip ? array?

Comment: @Aditi if list of ip is  array see this example http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#102898

Comment: Why for this case it will be 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.3 and 192.168.1.5-192.168.1.6 instead of 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.6??
I am not getting your point..

Comment: Because 192.168.1.4 is missing that's why i cant merge into single range . As it will depend on user what input he gives

Comment: check if manual method works or not (See my answer). I did it without using ip2long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `ip2long` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php that Converts a string containing an (IPv4) Internet Protocol dotted address into a proper address with this you can have a range like

```
echo ip2long('192.168.1.1');//-1062731519

echo ip2long('192.168.1.6');//-1062731514
```

with this you can check ip range of user ,... for valid or ,...

for example if user ip is in 192.168.1.1-192.168.1.6 range `echo 'hello';`

```
//http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php#81030
function in_ip_range($ip_one, $ip_two=false){ 
  if($ip_two===false){ 
    if($ip_one==$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']){ 
        $ip=true; 
    }else{ 
        $ip=false; 
    } 
  }else{ 
    if(ip2long($ip_one)<=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) && ip2long($ip_two)>=ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])){ 
        $ip=true; 
    }else{ 
        $ip=false; 
    } 
  } 
  return $ip; 
 } 
 //usage 
 if(in_ip_range('192.168.1.1','192.168.1.6')){
    echo 'hello';
 }
```

ip group

```
  $list=array(
   '192.168.1.1',
   '192.168.1.2',

   '192.168.1.3',

   '192.168.1.5',

   '192.168.1.6',
   '192.168.1.6',
   '192.168.1.9'
 );
 $Grouplist='';
 foreach($list as $ip){ 
       $ip2long=ip2long($ip);
       if(is_array($Grouplist)){
            $is_group=false;
            foreach($Grouplist as $Key=>$Range){
                 $Range=explode("/",$Range);
                 if(($Range[0]-1)<$ip2long and $ip2long<($Range[1]+1)){
                       $is_group=true;
                       continue;
                 }elseif(($Range[0]-1)==$ip2long){
                       $Grouplist[$Key]=$ip2long.'/'.$Range[1];
                       $is_group=true;
                 }elseif(($Range[1]+1)==$ip2long){
                      $Grouplist[$Key]=$Range[0].'/'.$ip2long;
                      $is_group=true;
                 }
            }
            if(!$is_group)
            {
                  $Grouplist[]=($ip2long).'/'.($ip2long);
            }
       }else{
             $Grouplist[]=($ip2long).'/'.($ip2long);
       }
 }
     print_r($Grouplist);
```

output:

```
 Array
(
   [0] => -1062731519/-1062731517  
   [1] => -1062731515/-1062731514
   [2] => -1062731511/-1062731511
)
```

that if convert to ip group is

```
foreach($Grouplist as $Val){
     $Range=explode("/",$Val);
     echo long2ip($Range[0])."/".long2ip($Range[1])."\n";
}
```

output

```
192.168.1.1/192.168.1.3
192.168.1.5/192.168.1.6
192.168.1.9/192.168.1.9
```

Comment: but this does not answer OP's question. OP wants grouping of IPs

Comment: i wait for @Aditi answer what is the list of ip ? Array?

Comment: check if manual method works or not (See my answer). I did it without using ip2long.

Comment: @Veekay as far as i know ip2long work for all version of php 4 and 5

Comment: @Veekay see the ip2long manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php work for (PHP 4, PHP 5) and it enable for default

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer :

```
$ip_list = array('192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.6');
$ip_long_list = array();
foreach($ip_list as $ip) {
  $ip_long_list[] = ip2long($ip);
}
unset($ip_list); // no longer in use 
sort($ip_long_list); // sort it

$result = array();
$cnt_group = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < count($ip_long_list)-1; $i++) {
  if($i == 0) {
    $result[$cnt_group] = array($ip_long_list[0]); // initialize 1st group
    continue;
  }
  if(abs($ip_long_list[$i] - $ip_long_list[$i+1]) == 1) {
    // they are in series, group it.
    $tmp_array = $result[$cnt_group]; // get back the array
    $tmp_array[] = $ip_long_list[$i]; // push item into array
    $result[$cnt_group] = $tmp_array;
    unset($tmp_array); // remove to save memory
  } else {
    // they are separate. next group.
    $cnt_group++;
    $result[$cnt_group] = array($ip_long_list[1]);
  }
}
```

After all the above, convert back to IP from Long.

```
foreach($result as $ip_long_group) {
  $first_ip = long2ip($ip_long_group[0]);
  $last_ip = long2ip($ip_long_group[count($ip_long_group)-1];

  $common_parts = longest_common_substring(array($first_ip, $last_ip));

  echo $common_parts . str_replace($common_parts, '', $first_ip) . '-' . str_replace($common_parts, '', $last_ip) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

*Note: I used a 3rd party function (listed in Reference) to get the common parts of 2 strings.*

Reference: [longest_common_substring()](http://www.christopherbloom.com/2011/02/24/find-the-longest-common-substring-using-php/)

Comment: check if manual method works or not (See my answer). I did it without using ip2long.

Answer (score 1):

Manual method to get range (without using ip2long):

```
<?php  
 $ip_addressess=array(
   '192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2', '192.168.1.3', '192.168.1.5', '192.168.1.6', '192.168.1.7', '192.168.1.9', '192.168.1.10',   '192.168.1.11', '192.168.1.15', '192.168.1.16', '192.168.1.17');

foreach($ip_addressess as $ip_address){
    $break_ip[] = explode('.', $ip_address); //break ip address
 }
foreach($break_ip as $break){
    $numbers[] = $break[3]; //get last number of ip address
}
$commaList_ipaddress = implode(',', $numbers); //generate comma separated list of last digits of ip address
$missing = array();
$a =0 ;
for ($i = 1; $i <= max($numbers); $i++) {
    if (!in_array($i, $numbers))
    {       
        $missing[] = $i;
    $a++;

    } else{
    $new_ip_ranges[$a][] = $i;    
    }

}
$new_ip_ranges = array_values($new_ip_ranges); //rearrange the array
foreach($new_ip_ranges as $new_range){
    $min = min($new_range);
    $max  = max($new_range);    
    $min_range = $break_ip[0][0].'.'.$break_ip[0][1].'.'.$break_ip[0][2].'.'.$min;
    $max_range = $break_ip[0][0].'.'.$break_ip[0][1].'.'.$break_ip[0][2].'.'.$max;       
    $range[] = $min_range .'-'.$max_range; 

}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($range);


?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 192.168.2.1-192.168.2.3
    [1] => 192.168.2.5-192.168.2.7
    [2] => 192.168.2.9-192.168.2.11
    [3] => 192.168.2.15-192.168.2.17
)
```

Demo at [CodeFiddle>>](http://codepad.viper-7.com/9nlRXx)

Comment: Yes, it is possible as well, but if the IP range is similar to : `192.168.1.1` to `192.168.2.1`, it won't work.

Comment: yes.. I just did it manually for better knowledge of array. Thank you for your comment.. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function printCombinedIPs($ip_arr) {
    //$ip_arr = array('192.168.1.5','192.168.1.6');
    $k = NULL;
    $prev = -1;
    foreach ( $ip_arr as $ip ) {
        $octet = explode(".",$ip);
        $fourth = $octet[3];
        $net = $octet[0].".".$octet[1].".".$octet[2];

        if ( $fourth < $prev ) { 
            $prev = -1;
        }

        $end = $fourth;
        if ( $fourth - 1 != $prev ) {
            $start = $fourth;
            $rtn_arr[] = $k;
        }
        
        if ( $start == $end ) 
            $k = $net.".$end";
        else
            $k = $net.".$start-$end";

        $prev = $octet[3];
    }
    $rtn_arr[] = $k;
    array_shift($rtn_arr);
    return implode(", ", $rtn_arr); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different method, this outputs an implied range as opposed to a "range", but it's easily modified. This code is basically grouping IPs and then counting them; if there are more than 5 in a group, it's flagged as a wildcard, anything with 3-4 is an implied range, and anything with 1 or 2 is just an IP address.

```
$ip_addresses = array();
$ranges = array();

foreach($ip_addresses as $ip) {
    if (str_contains($ip, '.')) {
        $piece = explode('.', $ip);
        $three = $piece[0] . '.' . $piece[1] . '.' . $piece[2];
        $ranges[$three][] = $piece[3];
    }
}

foreach ($ranges as $range => $ips) {
    if (count($ips) < 2) {
        foreach ($ips as $ip) {
            echo $range . '.' . $ip . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    if (count($ips) == 3 || count($ips) == 4) {
        sort($ips);
        echo $range . '.' . str_replace($range, '', $ips[0]) . '-' . str_replace($range, '', end($ips)) . PHP_EOL;
    }

    if (count($ips) >= 5) {
        echo $range . '.*' . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.